# How to follow Stack Overflow blog?

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, feed

I prefer to find out about the entries posted on https://stackoverflow.blog from an RSS Reader, instead of enacting https://xkcd.com/281/

What feed(s) should I subscribe to? The obvious one is https://stackoverflow.blog/feed/ but it is far from comprehensive: for example, the podcasts 109+ are missing from it. It turns out there is a separate feed for podcasts, https://stackoverflow.blog/?feed=podcast

But some posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/06/3-tips-freelance-developer/) are not included in either of those feeds. How to follow the complete stream of posts on https://stackoverflow.blog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the new year, we're hoping to add new subscription options to the blog (email list, better RSS feeds, etc.) Once these launch, I'll be sure to update you and let you know.

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.blog/feed/ is the canonical feed for all posts on the blog.

Missing posts on that feed is a bug.